# read an excel sheet which have multiple sheets and without table

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have an excel sheet which contain 10 sheets and saved inside SharePoint document library. and i want to do the following:-

1. read the data of a single sheet named "CompnayInfo" , the sheet contain the first row as headers and have filters but the sheet does not have table.

So how i can read this excel sheet rows? here is a screen shot of the excel sheet:-

Comment: Could you share the screenshot?

Comment: Do you want to get only the range visible from a filtered range? Are you restricted to power-automate?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to give you a fairly generic answer but you can take it from there and it will give you a result.

You can use the `Run script` action in the Excel online connector(s).  It allows you to write a script using the `Office Scripts` framework which composes of a set of typescript classes, etc. that allows you to work with Excel workbooks stored in SharePoint or OneDrive.

It' like VBA but for the web.  However, it's not as complete as VBA, but, it does near on everything you'd ever need and that which isn't catered for can be achieved via alternative means.

[image: Run script]

This is the script I put together, it's basic but gives you all of the data.  You'd need to do the work to enhance it and make it more useful for you.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, worksheetName: string) {
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(worksheetName);
    return worksheet.getUsedRange().getValues();
}
```

If you need to know how to create a script, follow these links and please note, for absolute ease, use the excel web client to create the script, the desktop version is around but don't complicate it for yourself and go through the web, it's tried and tested ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-office-scripts-in-excel-9fbe283d-adb8-4f13-a75b-a81c6baf163a

For the worksheet I ran the script over, this was the resulting JSON.  It's a 2 dimensional array by rows and columns of data ...

```
[
  [
    "Date",
    "Time",
    "g/l ni",
    "ECV808Ha",
    "Multiple"
  ],
  [
    44698.64584,
    44698.64584,
    4,
    5,
    20
  ],
  [
    44698.64928,
    44698.64928,
    5,
    15,
    75
  ],
  [
    44698.65506,
    44698.65506,
    5.2,
    4.8,
    24.96
  ],
  [
    44698.66566,
    44698.66566,
    4,
    45,
    180
  ],
  [
    44699.63499,
    44699.63499,
    8.6,
    9.3,
    79.98
  ],
  [
    44699.63914,
    44699.63914,
    15.2,
    8.2,
    124.64
  ],
  [
    44699.64223,
    44699.64223,
    14.2,
    18.6,
    264.12
  ],
  [
    44699.6455,
    44699.6455,
    8.2,
    2.6,
    21.32
  ],
  [
    44699.65178,
    44699.65178,
    15,
    15.2,
    228
  ],
  [
    44699.66725,
    44699.66725,
    14,
    12.2,
    170.8
  ],
  [
    44699.67292,
    44699.67292,
    15,
    16,
    240
  ],
  [
    44699.67413,
    44699.67413,
    12.2,
    13.4,
    163.48
  ],
  [
    44700.50296,
    44700.50296,
    4,
    2.5,
    10
  ],
  [
    44700.50534,
    44700.50534,
    5,
    8,
    40
  ],
  [
    44700.52765,
    44700.52765,
    4.5,
    8.6,
    38.7
  ],
  [
    44700.52861,
    44700.52861,
    8.5,
    4.2,
    35.7
  ],
  [
    44700.5975,
    44700.5975,
    8,
    14,
    112
  ],
  [
    44700.60117,
    44700.60117,
    4,
    8,
    32
  ],
  [
    44700.60197,
    44700.60197,
    4,
    2.5,
    10
  ],
  [
    44700.60348,
    44700.60348,
    4.5,
    5.25,
    23.625
  ],
  [
    44700.60414,
    44700.60414,
    80,
    2.5,
    200
  ],
  [
    44700.60597,
    44700.60597,
    4,
    2.5,
    10
  ],
  [
    44700.61531,
    44700.61531,
    8,
    6,
    48
  ],
  [
    44700.645,
    44700.645,
    4,
    2.5,
    10
  ],
  [
    44700.64679,
    44700.64679,
    4,
    4.5,
    18
  ],
  [
    44700.6484,
    44700.6484,
    8,
    6.2,
    49.6
  ],
  [
    44700.64964,
    44700.64964,
    6,
    6,
    36
  ],
  [
    44701.38266,
    44701.38266,
    4,
    5,
    20
  ],
  [
    44701.40955,
    44701.40955,
    5,
    5.5,
    27.5
  ],
  [
    44701.41484,
    44701.41484,
    8,
    6,
    48
  ],
  [
    44701.41723,
    44701.41723,
    8,
    65,
    520
  ],
  [
    44701.42251,
    44701.42251,
    4,
    6,
    24
  ],
  [
    44701.42304,
    44701.42304,
    4,
    8,
    32
  ],
  [
    44701.42365,
    44701.42365,
    8,
    90,
    720
  ],
  [
    44701.42384,
    44701.42384,
    8,
    60,
    480
  ],
  [
    44701.42045,
    44701.42045,
    4,
    5,
    20
  ],
  [
    44701.43058,
    44701.43058,
    18,
    16,
    288
  ],
  [
    44704.3115,
    44704.3115,
    4,
    8,
    32
  ],
  [
    44704.43532,
    44704.43532,
    6,
    525,
    3150
  ],
  [
    44704.44973,
    44704.44973,
    5,
    6,
    30
  ]
]
```

[image: Worksheet]

... If you write your own script, you can return specific JSON structures that suit your requirement.

Comment: ok thanks, but where do you define the range A2 to E18 in your case?

Comment: The call to .getUsedRange() gave me the entire used range of the cells on that sheet.

Comment: ok i see so where i need to add the script inside the excel sheet?

Comment: Follow the links, it shows you what to do. You don’t embed a script inside a workbook, they’re saved in the cloud and can be used across any workbook as long as you make them generic enough.

Comment: ok thanks but used cells means even the cells for the headers?

Comment: Yeah but you can define the range or if you name a range, you can just refer to that. This is your answer though, you just need to adapt it. My suggestion, use this answer, start exploring and then if you have specific issues, post another question. You can also get the data without headers if it’s a table. I’ve referred to the worksheet, not the table. That’s a different object and code.

Comment: John, if you're not confident with adapting my answer, let me ask you this, is the first row a true header or is it across multiple rows? You previously had a screenshot but it's gone and it didn't look like a true one row header. Your question is missing a lot of information. Also, what about the filters? Do they need to be applied in the output?

Comment: Maybe calling `getVisibleView()` will return filtered range `return worksheet.getUsedRange().getVisibleView().getValues();`